# XSL - Best practices for simple but verbose conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a `XML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Green</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Black</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>White</Color>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

And one `XSL` file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Vehicles>
            <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
                <Vehicle>
                    <VehicleColor>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                    </VehicleColor>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Color = 'Yellow' or Color = 'Green' or Color ='Blue'">
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Vehicle>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Vehicles>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleColor>Yellow</VehicleColor>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleColor>Green</VehicleColor>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleColor>Blue</VehicleColor>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleColor>Black</VehicleColor>
        <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleColor>White</VehicleColor>
        <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
    </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

I want to display the element if the color is different from Yellow, Green or Blue. 
It works but how to do this otherwise ? It's not pretty like that and I have a lot of colors

How to create a array with all the forbidden colors for example ?

I use only `XSL` 1.0

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@michael.hor257k's solution is neat, but here's another way to do/think of it: Create templates for each "forbidden" color that output your minimal version, and another template that matches all (i.e. all other) colors to output the full version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Vehicles>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Vehicles>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Car">
        <Vehicle>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Vehicle>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Yellow']">
        <VehicleColor>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </VehicleColor>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Green']">
        <VehicleColor>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </VehicleColor>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Blue']">
        <VehicleColor>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </VehicleColor>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color">
        <VehicleColor>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </VehicleColor>
        <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're worried about repetitive code, you could use a call template as well like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Vehicles>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Vehicles>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Car">
        <Vehicle>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Vehicle>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Yellow']">
        <xsl:call-template name="vehicle-color" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Green']">
        <xsl:call-template name="vehicle-color" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color[. = 'Blue']">
        <xsl:call-template name="vehicle-color" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Color">       
        <xsl:call-template name="vehicle-color" />
        <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="vehicle-color">
        <VehicleColor>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </VehicleColor>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This isn't **exactly** the approach you've asked for, but it feels a little more like native XSLT than an attempt to get the processor to think using custom arrays/lists.

Comment: I don't think this is very elegant. However, I don't think it deserves a down vote, certainly not one without an explanation. Voting up to offset.

Comment: The longer the list of colors gets, the more unwieldy this approach will be. If anything, you could write a template that matches `Color[. = 'Yellow' or . = 'Green']` and so on, but it would still be more cumbersome than Michael's solution. His solution is to open the stylesheet itself as an XML file and then apply expressions to it - that's actually "native XSLT" in my opinion. (I did not downvote btw.)

Comment: Yes, the templates certainly could be refactored to use an `or`, but with or without that is this really that much more to manage than having an "array" inside the stylesheet?  Also, I'm not trying to criticize @michael.hor257k's solution, but I think there'd be situations where it wouldn't be an option (if you're using .NET's XSLT capabilities I don't think it'd work, for example).  Then again, if you're using .NET you could use some C# or JScript code...

Comment: Ah, it would work in .NET I believe.  I must've been thinking of something else.

Answer (score 2):

> How to create a array with all the forbidden colors for example ?

Here's one way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<my:forbidden-colors>
    <color>Yellow</color>
    <color>Green</color>
    <color>Blue</color>
</my:forbidden-colors>

<xsl:template match="/Cars">
    <Vehicles>
        <xsl:for-each select="Car">
            <Vehicle>
                <VehicleColor>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                </VehicleColor>
                <xsl:if test="not(Color = document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:forbidden-colors/color)">
                    <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
                </xsl:if>
            </Vehicle>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Vehicles>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here's another (modeled after your original approach, actually):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Cars">
    <Vehicles>
        <xsl:for-each select="Car">
            <Vehicle>
                <VehicleColor>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                </VehicleColor>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Color = 'Yellow'"/>
                    <xsl:when test="Color = 'Green'"/>
                    <xsl:when test="Color = 'Blue'"/>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <VehicleStatus>ok</VehicleStatus>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </Vehicle>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Vehicles>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```